# How to get columns from table 1 to table 3

Tags: sql-server

T_category:

CatID(PK)|CatName

T_Log:

LogID(PK)|CatID(FK)

T_Report:

ReportID|LogID(FK)

is it possible to get CatName from T_Category in T_Report table

> want output like :
>
> T_Report: ReportID| LogID | CatName

Comment: Not sensibly unless your T_Log has a FK relationship to T_Category.  Otherwise you have a cross join, which I doubt will be meaningful.

Comment: check now. Chenged question @JonathanWillcock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT r.*, c.CatName FROM T_Report r INNER JOIN T_Log l ON
r.LogId = l.LogID INNER JOIN T_Category c ON c.CatID = l.CatID
```

should do the trick for you.